# How to differentiate indefinite integral of multivariable function, which is infinite at one endpoint

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation

I wish to verify that

$$\phi(r,t) = \int_r^\infty \frac{f_1(ct-R)}{\sqrt(R^2-r^2)}dR + \int_r^\infty \frac{f_2(ct+R)}{\sqrt(R^2-r^2)}dR,$$

where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are arbitrary functions, satisfies the axially symmetric wave equation,

$$\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}) - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial t^2} = 0.$$

This solution is given in Section 71 of [Fluid Mechanics by Landau and Lifschitz (Vol 6)](https://users-phys.au.dk/srf/hydro/Landau+Lifschitz.pdf).

I am unsure how to take the derivatives with respect to $r$ and $t$ of the given solution $\phi$, ie my question is, "What are $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$?"

I am aware of the [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule), however my issue here is that that the upper bound on both integrals is $\infty$, as well as the fact that evaluating the integrands at $r$ is undefined...

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I made a mistake and the PDE I gave is not solved by the given function $\phi$. I misunderstood what the textbook was saying. Sorry!

Comment: What do you usually do with an [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) to have a finite endpoint (which you can then push out to infinity)?

Comment: @EricTowers In this case, I see that I can write the integral as the limit of a definite integral, however I guess I'm unsure if I can (a) still apply the Leibniz rule to this (ie interchange partial differentiation and taking the limit) and (b) even use the Leibniz rule in the first place since the integrands evaluated at $r$ are undefined.

Comment: Improper integrals also deal with the singularity in the integrand at $R = r$, using a limit as the lower bound approaches $r$ from above.